# How to create a complex board outline for KiCad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I would like to create a board border featuring more complex arcs, constrained shapes, etc. for use in KiCad (and compatible tools like Topor). The internal tools are much worse than what other programs offer.
So what would be the best way to import an externally created shape (for example from an SVG file) to the cuts layer in KiCad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

KiCad can import the outline as DXF, which would be the easiest way. You can select upon import which layer to use. I think it can only handle lines though, so you might have to convert the shape to lines in your CAD tool first.

---

### [image]

[image]